# Gradle: "Empty" Android project takes half a minute to compile (Android Studio)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I've been trying different IDE's for months now and I could never find any that builds faster than the ancient Eclipse.

My "bigger" Android projects take almost a minute to compile so I checked how long a project that's created by using the **"Empty Activity"** preset and absolutely no additional code: **it's 20-30 seconds on a 2015 MacBook Air**.

How can the "modern" IDE's be so slow? Am I doing something wrong? I am literally taking ALL the stock-settings Android Studio has been installed with. I can't be the only one with this problem because it's also happening on my older Macs and on my Linux machines. I haven't tried windows tho

Any ideas?

Edit: the "bigger" projects I am talking about take about 10%-20% of the time in Eclipse. It's not just faster, it's like overtaking the other IDE's by a landslide

Edit2: I updated EVERYTHING I found upon creating the project. I am on gradle:2.1.3

Comment: Is your Eclipse using Gradle to build as well? I bet you would see similar speeds if so. Gradle does more than just compile and install the code on the device

Answer (score 1):

First, a Macbook Air is not a fast machine. 20-30 seconds sounds about right.

Second, it's not the IDE, it's Gradle that is the build tool. The IDE just invokes Gradle.

Third, Gradle-based builds aren't (can't) be any faster than Eclipse or the deprecated Ant-based build system. The part that's slow, dexopt, is the same in each case it's just a different toolchain that's invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'. Go to
**Android Studio** -> **File** -> **Setting** -> **Build,Execution,Deployment** -> **Gradle** -> check the "Offline Work" box.

Comment: That would prevent new dependencies from being downloaded, though

Comment: Irrelevant. After the first run, it would have downloaded and locally cached any dependencies.